# How to pick elements in fixed interval in an array (python)

Tags: arrays, python-2.7

Given array=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

I want to choose the 0-th 2-nd, 4-th index value to build a new array

array1=[1, 3, 5]

Could someone show me how to do using python? Thanks~

Answer (score 6):

If it is just `0`, `2`, and `4`, you can use [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter

array1 = itemgetter(0, 2, 4)(array)
```

That will be a tuple.  If it must be a list, convert it:

```
array1 = list(itemgetter(0, 2, 4)(array))
```

If the point is to get the even numbered indices, use slicing:

```
array1 = array[::2]
```

Whichever you are looking for, you could use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
array1 = [array[i] for i in (0, 2, 4)]
```

or

```
array1 = [array[i] for i in xrange(0, len(array), 2)]
```

Comment: Thanks very much~ If I want to set the "step",which is the picking interval, how could I do? For example, I want to pick elements at 0,3,6 indices or 0,4,8~

Comment: @Echo0831, you can achieve that by writing `array1 = [array[i] for i in xrange(start, len(array), step)]`, where start should be the index of the first element and step is the step size. Or you can see my answer.

Comment: @Echo0831: When I say `array[::2]`, that means all items in `array` from one end to the other with a step of `2`.  Therefore, you can just change the `2` to whatever step you want.  In `array1 = [array[i] for i in xrange(0, len(array), 2)]`, I say to go from an index of `0`, the first element, to the index of the length of the array - 1, the last element, with a step of `2`.  Therefore, you can change the `2` to whatever step you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. In python the nth term of a list has index `(n-1)`. Suppose the first element you want is 2, which happens to be the element 1 of `array`. Just save the first element index in a variable. Append it to the new list `array1` and increase the index by 2. Continue doing this until the list `array` is exhausted.

```
from numpy import*
array=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
array1=[]
term=1
while term<len(array):   # if the array length is 6 then it will have upto element 5.
    array1.append(array[term])
    term=term+2          # 2 is the gap between elements. You can replace it with your required step size.
```

Comment: Got you! make sense~